# How to pass multiple commands through adb shell using python script without exiting the shell

Tags: android, python, adb

I am trying to access adb shell of an android device and pass multiple commands such as

```
adb root
adb shell

cd /data/local/tmp
export PATH =/data/local/tmp:$PATH
export PATH =/data/local/tmp/testcases:$PATH
sh ./runltp -p -l 1213reportipc.log -d /data/local/tmp/LTP13/tmp -f ipc1q
exit
```

While I am able to do this manually using adb shell, I am unable to do this via a Python script since as soon script execution encounters 'adb shell' command it spawns a new internal shell and rest of the commands are not executed.

Can anyone please help me with this.

Comment: What is your Python script? You can also use `adb shell [command]` directly (it will only execute `[command]`).

Comment: Yes but only one command like adb shell (cd /data/) works. I want to enter multiple lines of code as explained above. I am using Python 2.7.12

Answer (score 0):

Use a text editor such as sublime or something, write your full adb script using subprocess to send commands and run it while your laptop is connected to your phone and USB debugging is switched on.

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call("adb shell <your command here>", shell = True)
subprocess.call("adb shell tap 172 3241", shell = True)   -- example
```

etc, just put your commands after the 'adb shell' and run the python script. This should type all your commands into the adb shell. You should even be able to enter commands such as
`subprocess.call("adb kill-server", shell=True)`
or `subprocess.call("adb root", shell=True)`